# Proving a this sequence converges using epsilon definition

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am not certain how to prove this sequence converge using the epsilon definition

Here is the sequence

$a_j=\frac{j^2+3}{2j^2-j+9}$

I turned the sequence into a function and for the limit I got

$j \rightarrow\infty \frac{j^2+3}{2j^2-j+9}=\frac{1}{2}$

So for the delta epsilon proof I have to find a number M such that for all

j>M then $|\frac{j^2+3}{2j^2-j+9}-\frac{1}{2}|<\epsilon$

I having trouble finding M

This is my work
$|\frac{j^2+3}{2j^2-j+9}-\frac{1}{2}|<\epsilon$

$=|\frac{(2)(j^2+3-(2j^2-j+9)}{2(2j^2-j+9)}|<\epsilon$

$=|\frac{j-3}{4j^2-j+9}|<\epsilon$

$=|(\frac{1}{j})\frac{1-3/j}{4-1/j+9/j}|<\epsilon$

I am not sure, what to do now

I guess find an integer larger than my rightmost fraction but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use that $|j-3|<j$  and $2j^2-j>j^2$ for $j\ge2$, you get that

$\displaystyle\frac{|j-3|}{2(2j^2-j+9)}<\frac{j}{2j^2-j+9}<\frac{j}{2j^2-j}<\frac{j}{j^2}=\frac{1}{j}$ for $j\ge 2$;

so now you just need to ensure that $j\ge 2$ and $\frac{1}{j}<\epsilon$.

Comment: i see so M will will be the max among 1/e and 2 in this proof.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez That's right.